# Grafana: Configure InfluxDB queries from panel plugin.Problem with html input element after setting value from typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, grafana

I have modified an existing Grafana panel plugin (Boom table) so that it can read a configuration file, and update patterns and thresholds with data from that file.

Now I would like to also update the Data Source queries and aliases to match the patterns. I am using InfluxDB. I have managed to, from my modified panel plugin, fill in the correct queries and aliases, but the problem is that I cannot manage to “apply” the alias. The query string I can apply by just making a select command from the typescript code, but this does not work on the alias input.

I am doing this by reading all input fields with document.getElementsByClassName("gf-form-input"). From the array with HTMLInputElements that is returned, I have figured out which inputs that are queries and aliases and updated it by setting the value. I have tried both setting it with `input.value = "<alias string>"` and `input.setAttribute('value', <alias string>)`.

Apart from “select”, I have also tried various other commands, like: “click”, “focus” and “blur”. I can see that the correct text is filled in to the correct input box, but the table with the data above is not updated. If I manually change a character it applies and the table is updated correctly. Does anyone have any idea how I could make this work? It feels like I am very close to achieving what I need, it’s just the last piece that is missing. It would be very nice if I can use the standard InfluxDB Data Source plugin and only modify the panel plugin.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event needs to be triggered via angular.

See the following liuk:
https://tommcfarlin.com/triggering-angular-events-with-jquery/

The following code taken from the link above is the example to which solves the issue:

```js
$('select[ng-model="schedule.payment_method"]').each(function() {

  // For the purposes of this example, we're going to select the first option.
  $(this)
    .children('option:eq(1)')
    .attr('selected', 'selected');

  // Make sure the select element reflects the change (as setting the option doesn't always do this properly).
  $(this).val($(this).children('option:selected').attr('value'));

  // Now use the Angular API's triggerHandler function to call the change.
  angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('change');
});
```

Update the initial jquery selector to that of your alias box.

EDIT:
Just doing some testing and you should be able to simply execute

```
angular.element($0).triggerHandler("change")
```

After changing the value, where $0 is the dom object of the alias box.